# loop nested list that contains value that dinamically return a list Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to match ip with a port.
The var I receive is this kind that could have several source-ports blocks:

```
vars:
    networks: 
      - source: 10.135.4.23/25
        ports:  
          - 80
          - 25
```

I need to loop each ports of each network block, and inside that loop, loop the source (ip range), to match each port with each ip.

This is what I tried:

```
- name: Show network info
      set_fact:
        network_item: "{{ network_item|default([]) + [network | ansible.utils.nthhost(item)] }}"
      loop: "{{ query('sequence', 'start=0 end='+(network|ansible.utils.ipaddr('net')|ansible.utils.ipaddr('size')|string)) }}"
```

This block return the list of the ips, but I don't have the ports so no possible match.

So, I tried this task:

```
- name: Show network info
      set_fact:
        network_item: "{{ network_item|default([]) + [{'source': item.source | ansible.utils.nthhost(item), 'ports': item.ports}] }}"
      with_subelements:
        -"{{ networks }}"
        -"{{ query('sequence', 'start=0 end='+(source|ansible.utils.ipaddr('net')|ansible.utils.ipaddr('size')|string)) }}"
```

In order to create a var named network_item to store the list of ips and ports to make the pairs in another task, but return the error Unrecognized type <<class 'ansible.template.AnsibleUndefined'>> for ipaddr filter <value>

Also, I tried this code, but match the range to each port.

```
- name: Loop over networks and ports
      debug:
        msg: "IP: {{ item.0 }} - Port: {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ networks }}"
        - ports
```

No solution for now.
What I would achieve is like in this last code block, a way to add a loop inside with_subelements with the loop from the first code block, that get the range and return the ip on each loop.

Is that possible to accomplish with Ansible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a valid solution.

I can see that to achieve 3 level nested loops it should be done with separated .yml files. I think then that infinite level nested loops could be achieved in the same way. In my case I do it that way:

main.yml

```
vars:
networks: 
  - source: 10.135.4.23/25
    ports:  
      - 80
      - 25

tasks:

- name: Looping over networks
  include_tasks: inner_loop.yml
  loop: "{{ networks }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: network_item
```

inner_loop.yml

```
- name: Looping over ports
  include_tasks: inner_inner_loop.yml
  loop: "{{ network_item.ports  }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: port_to_check
```

inner_inner_loop.yml

```
- name: Show network info
   - name: Test connectivity
     wait_for:
      host: "{{ network_item.source | ansible.utils.nthhost(item) }}"
      port: "{{ port_to_check }}"
      timeout: 1
      state: started
      loop: "{{ query('sequence', 'start=1 end='+((network_item.source|ansible.utils.ipaddr('net')|ansible.utils.ipaddr('size')-1)|string)) }}"
      register: result
      when: not condition
      vars:
       condition: "{{ (result|default({'failed':true})).failed == false}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, given the list of networks for testing

```yaml
  networks:
    - source: 10.135.4.0/29
      ports: [80, 25]
    - source: 10.135.5.0/30
      ports: [80, 25]
```

create the YAML list of all IP addresses and their ports

```yaml
  networks_list: |
    [{% for n in networks %}
    {% set net = n.source|ansible.utils.ipaddr('net') %}
    {% set size = net|ansible.utils.ipaddr('size') %}
    {% for idx,port in range(1, size - 1)|product(n.ports) %}
    {{ net|ansible.utils.nthhost(idx) }}:{{ port }},
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}]
```

and convert the list from YAML. Use it in a loop

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ networks_list|from_yaml }}"
```

gives abridged

```yaml
  msg: 10.135.4.1:80
  msg: 10.135.4.1:25
  msg: 10.135.4.2:80
  msg: 10.135.4.2:25
  msg: 10.135.4.3:80
  msg: 10.135.4.3:25
  msg: 10.135.4.4:80
  msg: 10.135.4.4:25
  msg: 10.135.4.5:80
  msg: 10.135.4.5:25
  msg: 10.135.4.6:80
  msg: 10.135.4.6:25
  msg: 10.135.5.1:80
  msg: 10.135.5.1:25
  msg: 10.135.5.2:80
  msg: 10.135.5.2:25
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
│   └── all
│       └── networks_list.yml
├── hosts
├── networks.yml
└── pb.yml

2 directories, 5 files
```

Put the expressions into the *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/networks_list.yml 
networks_list_str: |
  [{% for n in networks|d([]) %}
  {% set net = n.source|ansible.utils.ipaddr('net') %}
  {% set size = net|ansible.utils.ipaddr('size') %}
  {% for idx,port in range(1, size - 1)|product(n.ports) %}
  {{ net|ansible.utils.nthhost(idx) }}:{{ port }},
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}]
networks_list: "{{ networks_list_str|from_yaml }}"
```

and create the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ networks_list }}"
```

Create a file with the data

```yaml
shell> cat networks.yml 
networks:
  - source: 10.135.4.0/29
    ports: [80, 25]
  - source: 10.135.5.0/30
    ports: [80, 25]
```

and use it in the command line

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e @networks.yml pb.yml | grep msg:
  msg: 10.135.4.1:80
  msg: 10.135.4.1:25
  msg: 10.135.4.2:80
  msg: 10.135.4.2:25
  msg: 10.135.4.3:80
  msg: 10.135.4.3:25
  msg: 10.135.4.4:80
  msg: 10.135.4.4:25
  msg: 10.135.4.5:80
  msg: 10.135.4.5:25
  msg: 10.135.4.6:80
  msg: 10.135.4.6:25
  msg: 10.135.5.1:80
  msg: 10.135.5.1:25
  msg: 10.135.5.2:80
  msg: 10.135.5.2:25
```

You can fit the template to your needs. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/networks_list.yml
networks_list_str: |
  [{% for n in networks|d([]) %}
  {% set net = n.source|ansible.utils.ipaddr('net') %}
  {% set size = net|ansible.utils.ipaddr('size') %}
  {% for idx in range(1, size - 1) %}
  {ip: {{ net|ansible.utils.nthhost(idx) }}, ports: {{ n.ports }}},
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}]
networks_list: "{{ networks_list_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  networks_list:
    - ip: 10.135.4.1
      ports: [80, 25]
    - ip: 10.135.4.2
      ports: [80, 25]
    - ip: 10.135.4.3
      ports: [80, 25]
    - ip: 10.135.4.4
      ports: [80, 25]
    - ip: 10.135.4.5
      ports: [80, 25]
    - ip: 10.135.4.6
      ports: [80, 25]
    - ip: 10.135.5.1
      ports: [80, 25]
    - ip: 10.135.5.2
      ports: [80, 25]
```

You can iterate the list by the subelements. For example, the play below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.ip }}:{{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ networks_list }}"
        - ports
```

---

See:

- [Finding IP addresses within a range](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/docsite/filters_ipaddr.html#finding-ip-addresses-within-a-range)
- [Managing network interactions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-network-interactions)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Check my reply, I think is a better aproximation of what I need thank to your contribution.

Comment: Both answers iterate *`ansible.utils.nthhost(index)`*. Why do you think three nested loops in the code would be better? The same algorithm takes only 7 lines in the Jijnja2 expression.

Comment: Yes I see, I'm not saying its better than yours, but its better because it fits the need to control the loop by network blocks and by ports, because I need to check that if a network block is a success connection, stop checking with that port and start trying with the next

Comment: There is no *break* in Ansible loops. You can skip items but you can't break a loop. As a result, both algorithms are the same. This Q&A is completed, I think. Open a new question about checking the connection if you want to.